# Unlist a data frame by rows, not columns

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, unroll

A relatively simple question, but the answer seems to have eluded me. Currently, I have a data frame which looks similar to this:

```
0   0   0   1   1
0   1   0   1   1
2   1   1   0   3
```

I'm trying to turn this into a single line of data, by rows. I used the `unlist` function, and it did what I wanted, but gave them to me by columns. It gave me this:

```
0,0,2,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,3
```

but what I want is this:

```
0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,1,1,0,3
```

I apologize if this seems like a silly question, but I'm still a novice with R. Any help (or referrals to functions which might help me process this) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can take the transpose (`t`) of the dataset and then use `c` to get a vector output

```
 c(t(df1))
 #[1] 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 0 3
```

By doing transpose, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'matrix'.  In both `data.frame` or `matrix`, `unlist/c` operations happen columnwise.  So, transposing swaps the columns for rows and viceversa and we get the expected result.

Comment: Incredibly simple. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

You can try also `as.vector()`:

```
x<-matrix(c(0,0,2,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,3),3,5)

x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1    1
[3,]    2    1    1    0    3

as.vector(t(x))
[1] 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 0 3
```