# Collating or alternately merging two columns into one list in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there an easy way to alternately merge two columns into one list/dataframe column in R? Essentially I need to do a large series of manipulation of genetic data, sorting etc... and eventually I am left with an identifier and a sequence. What is the easiest way to create a single list that has each identifier above its sequence in a single list?

I have data:
`df <- data.frame(genenames = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3"), seqnes = c("gattaca", "gatgatcca", "catgatcat"))`

I would like to get to: 
 `data.frame(c("gene1", "gattaca", "gene2","gatgatcca", "gene3", "catgatcat"))`

using either
`unite(data, "identifier", "sequence", sep = " ")` will result in all data fuse within a single column as well as `stack(......)`

Is there an easy or elegant way to do this save starting to look into writing a small loop to iteratively write out the new list?

Comment: Probably this will help `c(t(df))`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989270/unlist-a-data-frame-by-rows-not-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one potential solution with `gather` from `tidyr`and some `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(obs = 1:nrow(df)) %>%
  gather(identifier, sequence, -obs) %>%
  arrange(obs, desc(identifier))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
> data.frame("wut"=unname(unlist(data.frame(t(df)))))
        wut
1     gene1
2   gattaca
3     gene2
4 gatgatcca
5     gene3
6 catgatcat
```

Answer (score 2):

Elegant one-liner. No column specs and loops are needed.

```
df <- data.frame(new_col = c(t(df)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a list:

```
lapply(apply(df, 1, identity), unlist)
```