# Unlist data in a particular order

Tags: r

I have a list of data generated using the below code:

```
rowcolfn <- function (df, colname) {
  which(df==(colname), arr.ind=TRUE)}
valuesvar<-c(4.9, 1.5, 0.2)
iris<-iris[1:5,]
datalist <- purrr::map(.x=valuesvar,
                        .f=rowcolfn,
                        df=iris)
```

I then unlist the data using `unlist(datalist)` and  the result of this is:
`2 1 4 3 1 2 3 4 5 4 4 4 4 4` whereas the result I want is: `2 1 4 3 1 4 2 4 3 4 4 4 5 4`

The problem is when datalist[[3]] unlists, it does the `row` column first eg 1,2,3,4,5 whereas I want it to be the `row` then `col` columns for the first line (1,4) and then to repeat like this down the list.

Any suggestions for how to achieve this?

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing, but you could achieve what you want by doing `c(t(datalist[[3]]))` this is becauseR is column major and not row major

Comment: `t()` is almost always the trick in those cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989270/unlist-a-data-frame-by-rows-not-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change `rowcolfn` to return the output in the order that you want and then `list_c()` the output to unlist.

```
library(purrr)

rowcolfn <- function (df, colname) {
  c(t(which(df==(colname), arr.ind=TRUE)))
}

map(.x=valuesvar,.f=rowcolfn,df=iris) |> list_c()
#[1] 2 1 4 3 1 4 2 4 3 4 4 4 5 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way using transpose function `t`:

```
unlist(lapply(datalist, t))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the rows in your list, and `t`ranspose + `c`oncatenate to get the unlisted values by row:

```r
c(t(do.call(rbind, datalist)))
#[1] 2 1 4 3 1 4 2 4 3 4 4 4 5 4
```